# Хэш в урл-е

Tags: drupal, jquery, ajax

[Здесь](http://zerde.gov.kz/#projects)  сделали, при нажатий на элементы меню в адресную строку добавляется хэш и аяксом загружаеть контент. Не скажете, какой должен быть алгоритм чтобы так же сделать?

Comment: присоединяюсь к вопросу + подвопрос: как с этим делом дружат поисковики?

Comment: присоединясь к вопросу о дружеских отношениях

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Оооо, это очень острый вопрос в веб-разработке и SEO. Гугл даже целый [микропротокол](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/) придумал для таких дел - там используется `hashbang` (`#!`), а не просто `#`. Но - поддерживается (пока?) только Гуглом. Иначе говоря, ваш контент, доступный только по `hashbang`-urlам индексирован не будет никем, кроме Гугла (при условии, что вы поддерживаете его протокол). То есть с поисковиками - все чертовски плохо.

НО! Если у вас документы через ajax подгружаются как непосредственно html-документы (а не как набор переменных в JSON, например, который потом будет использован в шаблоне на стороне клиента), возможно в исходном документе разместить именно эти ссылки (они будут видны поисковикам, ибо те не понимают JS), а при загрузке через JS сменить их на подлежащие загрузке через ajax. Возможно, это и будет работать, но тут другой подводный камень - гуглбот JS в некоторой мере понимает и не известно, как он отнесется к этому безобразию.

W3C против формата, предложенного Гуглом, ибо "ломает основную идею веб": каждому уникальному документу - уникальная ссылка. При подгрузке частей документа через ajax, во всяком случае. Если части документа будут в теле документа, не думаю, что это нанесет урон вебу. А вот при использовании ajax структура пострадает, ибо согласно спецификациям fragment (хэш) не является частью URI, и ссылки вида `example.com/#!one_stuff` и `example.com/#!another_stuff` - формально указывают на один и тот же ресурс.

А алгоритм простой. Отлавливаем событие `onhashchange` и ставим ему обработчик, который парсит хэш и на основе этих данных производит какие-то действия.

Для jQuery, например, даже несколько плагинов есть. Самый знаменитый - [BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/). Есть [jquery-history](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/), пользовался им однажды.